# Use a groupby instead of for loop to determine time spent in last locations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that records the movement of people from one location to another. I would like to calculate the time spent by each `person_id` in each `end_location_id` when not moving. The calculation is based on the difference between `start_ts` of the next new travel entry and the `end_ts` of the last travel entry, per `location_id`. If no new travel entry is found per person, then the calculation should be the difference between `current_time` and `end_ts`.

I would like to replace the code that calculates `duration` with code that uses pandas' groupby (or equivalent) functions. Would this be possible? My current code is messy.

```
import pandas as pd

current_time = '2022-05-05 17:00'

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "person_id": ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C"],
    "start_location_id": [1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 8],
    "end_location_id": [2, 6, 3, 8, 2, 9],
    "start_ts": pd.to_datetime(["2022-05-05 00:00", "2022-05-05 00:00", "2022-05-05 05:00", "2022-05-05 00:00", "2022-05-05 13:00", "2022-05-05 11:00"]),
    "end_ts": pd.to_datetime(["2022-05-05 02:00", "2022-05-05 03:00", "2022-05-05 10:00", "2022-05-05 04:00", "2022-05-05 16:00", "2022-05-05  12:00"]),
}
)

for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i, "duration"] = (df.loc[(df["person_id"] == df.loc[i, "person_id"]) & (df["start_location_id"] == df.loc[i, "end_location_id"]) & (df.index > i), "start_ts"].min() - df.loc[i, "end_ts"]).total_seconds()/3600

df.loc[df["duration"].isna(), "duration"] = (pd.to_datetime(current_time) -                 
df.loc[df["duration"].isna(), "end_ts"]).dt.total_seconds()/3600
```

My desired output would be:

```
print(df)
>>
  person_id  start_location_id  end_location_id            start_ts  \
0         A                  1                2 2022-05-05 00:00:00   
1         B                  5                6 2022-05-05 00:00:00   
2         A                  2                3 2022-05-05 05:00:00   
3         C                  7                8 2022-05-05 00:00:00   
4         A                  3                2 2022-05-05 13:00:00   
5         C                  8                9 2022-05-05 11:00:00   

               end_ts  duration  
0 2022-05-05 02:00:00       3.0  
1 2022-05-05 03:00:00      14.0  
2 2022-05-05 10:00:00       3.0  
3 2022-05-05 04:00:00       7.0  
4 2022-05-05 16:00:00       1.0  
5 2022-05-05 12:00:00       5.0
```

Comment: I understand how you get the first 3, but for person B, how can you compute a delta when there is only one row?

Comment: So for B, it would be current time - end_ts, meaning he is still in that location

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part, I see it now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shift per group ([`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html)), filling the NaN with your current time:

```
current_time = pd.Timestamp('2022-05-05 17:00') # works also with simple string

df['duration'] = (df
                  .groupby('person_id')['start_ts']
                  .shift(-1, fill_value=current_time)
                  .sub(df['end_ts'])
                  .dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
                 )
```

output:

```
  person_id  start_location_id  end_location_id            start_ts  \
0         A                  1                2 2022-05-05 00:00:00   
1         B                  5                6 2022-05-05 00:00:00   
2         A                  2                3 2022-05-05 05:00:00   
3         C                  7                8 2022-05-05 00:00:00   
4         A                  3                2 2022-05-05 13:00:00   
5         C                  8                9 2022-05-05 11:00:00   

               end_ts  duration  
0 2022-05-05 02:00:00       3.0  
1 2022-05-05 03:00:00      14.0  
2 2022-05-05 10:00:00       3.0  
3 2022-05-05 04:00:00       7.0  
4 2022-05-05 16:00:00       1.0  
5 2022-05-05 12:00:00       5.0
```